# Photoshop Memory issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm running into some major problems with Photoshop. This has just recently started to happen to me.

I'm running Photoshop cs3 extended  on Windows.

I've been trying to create some text with 2 colors (ie: HelloWorld - Hello is red, World is blue).

Everytime I go about doing this, Photoshop spits out the following error message to me:

"Could not complete your request because there is not enough memory (RAM)"

I'm running on 512 RAM with 3GB of HD left on my C: drive, and 5GB left on my D: drive. I don't know what could be causing this error.

I restarted everything but still same problem :(

Answer (score 7):

You can try upping the available ram for now, go to Edit> Preferences> Performance and put the available ram slider all the way to the right.

You should also upgrade your RAM! 512mb of RAM (random access memory) is not a lot in this day and age! I had to upgrade a few years ago when using CS2. Go to your local computer store and ask them for a RAM upgrade! Shouldn't cost much.

Comment: yes, good gravy, go get more RAM. I'm running 2 gigs and I still get complaints that I don't have enough memory. Virtual memory is never ever as fast as RAM.

Comment: Virtual memory is also the fast track to burning out a hard drive. Photoshop does a *lot* of memory swapping.

Comment: Yeah, it does. That's why I try to keep its use of Ram maximum and scratch disk space minimum, don't want another burned out harddrive!